# Select all distinct last records of column1 and order by column2 in Linq (Not Working Accordingly)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, linq

So I have a table like this:

[image]

Now I want distinct `ShortCode` order by the `ID` descending. In other words, the distinct last records. Like this:

[image]

So I tried GroupBy like:

```
var data = db.ShortCodes.GroupBy(x => x.ShortCode).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).OrderByDescending(s=> s.ID);
```

This gave me distinct records but not the last ones, nor ordered by ID descending:

[image]

Now I also tried like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636142/linq-distinct-and-orderby)

```
var data = db.ShortCodeManager
               .GroupBy(s => s. ShortCode)
               .Select(g => g.First())
               .OrderByDescending(s => s.ID);
```

This gave me the error `The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.`

So I modified to `FirstOrDefault()` like:

```
var data = db.ShortCodeManager
               .GroupBy(s => s. ShortCode)
               .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
               .OrderByDescending(s => s.ID);
```

This also gave me distinct records but not the last records:

[image]

So finally I tried like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940790/linq-to-sql-select-latest-distinct-entries):

```
var data = db.ShortCodeManager.Where(a => a.ID > 0).GroupBy(x => x.ShortCode).OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Max(g => g.ID)).Select(a => a.FirstOrDefault());
```

Again, this gave me distinct records but not the last ones, nor ordered by ID descending:

[image]

So how am I to write the query to get the result I want in Linq? Also note, I need more of the distinct last records than ordering by `ID` descending. If anyone also knows how to write it in raw SQL it might be useful as well.

Comment: The last one is a duplicate since you already have 1820.  I think you want to group by ID and Shortcut, not just Shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This LINQ query should work for your case:

```
var result = db.ShortCodeManager
    .GroupBy(x => x.ShortCode)
    .Select(gr => new { Id = gr.Max(g => g.Id), ShortCode = gr.Key})
    .ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment it looks like you need to cast anonymous object `result` to `ShortCodeManagerModel` type and then pass it to your view. So, somethin like this:

```
var result = db.ShortCodeManager
    .GroupBy(x => x.ShortCode)
    .Select(gr => new { Id = gr.Max(g => g.Id), ShortCode = gr.Key})
    .ToList();

var model = result 
    .Select(x => new ShortCodeManagerModel { Id = x.Id, ShortCode = x.ShortCode })
    .ToList();
```

And then pass `model` to you view.

Comment: I tried this but it seems like the model i send from the controller has chnaged. I get the error `System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Int16]]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[Models.ShortCodeManagerModel]'.`  Note in my view I have a model like `@model IEnumerable<Models.ShortCodeManagerModel>`

Comment: Hmm. I am not sure if I am missing something here, now I get the error `The entity or complex type 'Models.ShortCodeManagerModel' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.`. Note in your 1st answer, when I debug I see that the data it returns is the data I want in the view. But then I get the error I mentioned earlier in the view. As for the updated code, the error occurs in the query it self. Note that the `ShortCodeManagerModel` contains other attributes that I didn't mention as am only interested in the `ShortCode` and `Id` not sure if that makes a difference? Appreciate the help.